# Enum variable with value from properties

Tags: java, spring, enums, properties

I would like to have in my Enum a variable that value is readen from application.properties file. Is it possible to do this?
Enum:

```
public enum T {
    A;

    @Value("${test}")
    private String test;

}
```

Mapping from controller to test:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String main() {
    T t = T.A;
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}
```

Properties:

```
test = test
```

Now when I call T.A it is null. I need it to read from properties because this variable should be different on each server that app is running.

Comment: No. Enums are static and basically unmodifiable at runtime.

Comment: It seems to me like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you doing a translations? Your logic shouldn't be dependent on `T.test` value anyway. And how can `T.A` evaluate to `null` ? Did you mean `T.A.test`? I'd like to understand usage of that...

Answer (score 0):

Your enum is not a component, so you can't use `@Value`.

Like M. Deinum said: Enums are static, so they won't be wired in your Spring-context.

You could directly wire `@Value` in your Controller.

```
@Value("${test}")
private String test;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String main() {
   System.out.println(test);
   return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}
```